# power efficiency's definition

Tags: efficiency, charge-pump, voltage-doubler

Power Efficiency is defined as output power/input power, right?

And there are a little bit different definition of power efficiency ...output power/(output power+power loss).

Is these mean same thing? If so, why?

In voltage doubler(or think about just 1-stage Dickson charge pump,), output voltage is twice of input voltage. And if there a current source on its load, VDD provides same(or very similar) current with load's current source. Hence, output power is LARGER than input power! I know it is truely and utterly NONSENSE. Then how can i calculate/simulate the power efficiency?

[image]

Comment: "*Hence, output power is LARGER than input power!*", think again.

Comment: The problem with the output_power and power_loss definition is that your book-keeping has to be exquisitely thorough. Not many engineers can keep track of *all* the loss terms, and for amateurs it's a non-starter. It can be an interesting exercise though to compute power_loss as input_power - output_power, and then compare it with power_loss through totting up all of the loss terms you can identify. The difference between these is the measure to which you don't fully understand all the loss terms in the circuit!

Comment: @Neil_UK My problem is input power is lower than output power. It cannot be. How to measure P_in? Is it not enough for just measuring input current(because V_in is dc voltage source, providing 1V) ?

Comment: It depends how you're 'measuring' input power. If by the exhaustion of something you can measure absolutely, say running it from a big electrolytic capacitor, noting the fall of voltage over time, converting that to change of energy, then you'll get the right answer. If you try to approximate it, say by measuring a non-constant current with a DMM, and then multiplying that by a similarly approximated voltage, then you'll get all sorts of silly answers. The book-keeping has to be just as exquisitely correct on input power as it does for power loss terms.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: both are actually the same representation.

Let's start by a few definition:

**Input**: what goes in the system

**Output**: what goes out of the system or more usefully: what power is actually used by the intended purpose (movement, lighting, data transmission...doesn't matter).

If a system was perfect and without loss, the input power would be equal to the output power. However, no system is perfect. Therefore a certain percentage of the input energy is lost in the process. Most often, that loss is in the form of undesired heat.

To go back to your equation. The input power (what goes in) is equal to the output power (what goes out) plus the imperfection of the system (what is lost).

\$P_{in} = P_{out} + P_{loss}\$

You merely change \$P_{in}\$ in your first equation (\$\frac{P_{out}}{P_{in}}\$) to get your second equation.

For the second part of the question, by doubling the voltage, you will most likely reduce the current by roughly half at the output level. Therefore \$P_{in} = V×I\$ and \$P_{out} = \not{2}V×\frac{I}{\not{2}} - P_{loss}\$.

Any imperfection in the system will simply add up to what is outputted by the system. Some circuits may increase the total power output by using external sources during your process...In that case, it is simply a matter of taking into account those power injection throughout your circuit. But a passive circuit or a circuit that doesn't inject power along the way will always have an output that is less than the input.

Comment: Yeah. I measured that circuit with cadence, with condition of V_in=1V, I_L=500uA. And then, I_in was same with I_L. P_in = V_in*I_in, so, P_in = 1 * 500u = 500uW. And that circuit's output voltage is larger than V_in, because that one is voltage doubler, so V_out becomes 1.66V when i measuered. Then P_out = V _out * I_out = 1.66V * 500uA = 830uW. P_in is smaller than P_out. I know it is nonsenses, so please how to measure the proper power efficiency please.

Comment: @M.Kim did you remember to include the \$\phi{}_1\$ and \$\phi{}_2\$ current?

Comment: @immibis the average current that Pi_1 and Pi_2 provide are 1.09324uA

Comment: @M.Kim that's average current, what about average power? (which is not average current times average voltage)

Comment: @immibis 4.905mW, calaclate with cadence. P_out=830uW, P_in=4.905mW+0.5mW(by V_in) = 5.405mW. Then, Efficiency = 0.153.

Comment: @immibis but using another definition, the calculation of P_out / (P_out + P_loss) is 0.833.

Comment: @Harry Svensson Yeah output's load is constant dc current source, in my simulation load current is 500uA. Load current doesn't change. Voltage doubler is supposed to provide doubled voltage of V_in, but because of the presence of load current, it provides less then doubled voltage of V_in, such as 1.66V(if V_in = 1V).

Comment: @M.Kim How did you calculate P_loss?

Comment: @immibis P_loss is consists of load dependent loss, and load independent loss. Both losses are related with parasitic capacitors of flying caps.

Comment: @M.Kim Okay, how did you calculate the power loss? Because the power loss is all the power that came in the inputs and didn't go out the output (that's what it *means*). So it must be P_loss = P_in - P_out. If not, then something is missing from your calculations.

Comment: @immibis Power Loss = R_out*Io^2 + V_in^2 / R_in, R_out is voltage doubler's output impedance and R_in is voltage doubler's input impedance. R_out = 1 / (2* f_clk * C_fly) when except the parasitic capacitance. R_in would be infinite when except the parasitic caps.

Comment: @M.Kim Well something is wrong with that calculation because it doesn't seem to calculate the actual power loss. (It doesn't even account for the fact this circuit has three inputs)

Comment: @immibis oh, i mis-calculated the power that clock provides. with proper calculation, everything is alright. thanks for your idea-about clock provides unignorable power. Thank you!